# Location of printStackTrace() log when application is started in server

Tags: java, logging

I have a sample code like below in my class and I tried to start application in server. In our application we generally use logger.error to push the exceptions to error logs. By mistake I didnt keep logger.error and directly used `e.printStackTrace()` in catch block.

If we start application in local (Eclipse IDE), we get the entire stack trace printed in eclipse console. But if deploy application in server and start it in server (without using logger.error), where this exception will be printed?

Does the server creates a temporary log to store these kind of stack trace? If so, what is the path of this log file?

```
try {

    // ...

} catch (SomeException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Though it may sound silly, I have this doubt and I want to know where exception will be printed.

Many thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Dinesh

Comment: This should print the exception on your output stream which should be console.

Comment: Depends on which server you are using? Tomcat?

Comment: we deploy and start application in linux host

Comment: Are you using any logging framework if yes then check the location of the log files from configuration files. e.g  if log4j is used then you can find the log files location in log4j.xml

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what application server you are using and on logging configuration. But with Tomcat and default logging configuration there should be file named `catalina.out` where yout application is deployed.